# Count number of elements via Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

There are different types of boards, types can have multiple boards, and boards have multiple users.

Task: get the number of users for a specific type of boarding.

Model for types boarding:

```
class BoardingType extends Model
{
    public function boardings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Boarding::class, 'type');
    }
}
```

Model for boardings:

```
class Boarding extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'boarding');
    }
}
```

How can I concisely get all users for boarding types?

Made in a similar form, I do not like the implementation:

```
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $usersCount = 0;
    foreach ($type->boardings as $boarding) {
        $usersCount += $boarding->users()->count();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the flag about wrong language? In ruSO we have a flag which says that questions must be only in Russian language but I can't see this flag here. This question belongs to https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Can you translate your question in english please?

Comment: Sorry, made a translation of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [has-many-through](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship here.
In your `BoardingType` model

```
  public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Bording::class);
    }
```

Please note that you may have to specify the fk in case your model doesn't follow the laravel [key convention](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through-key-conventions):

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            User::class,
            Bording::class,
            'bording_type_id', // Foreign key on the boarding table...
            'boarding_id', // Foreign key on the users table...
            'id', // Local key on the bording type table...
            'id' // Local key on the boarding table...
        );
    }
```

you can count the number of users for a bording type like this:

```
$usersCount = $bordingType->users()->count();
```